# How can I make the trailing effect when a character runs by using Unity？

Tags: unity-game-engine, effect, trailing

Recently，I find a funny game called 《Chameleon Run》. It has very gorgeous effect when the character runs. How can I make the trailing effect like this by using Unity？Is there any plug-in？I cannot post pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that game, but, giving you a generic answer, trail effects can be achieved using a [Trail Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html). Attach it to your object, and adjust the parameters. You can also set a material, in order to totally customize the effect.

This is the example picture taken from the documentation, obviously using it in a 2D environment is also possible.

[image]